# Psycopg2 execute values -the query contains more than one '%s' placeholder

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to use psycopg2 execute_values for faster execute and keep getting errors so i guess i'm not writing the sql statement correct.

That's what i try:

```
  sql = """UPDATE table SET value1 = %s, value2 = %s, value3 = %s WHERE id = %s"""
for feat in features:
    value1=feat.value
    value2=feat.value
    value3=feat.value


    parameters = [
                value1,
                value2,
                value3,
               
            ]
    all_parameters.append(parameters)



execute_values(cur,sql,all_parameters)
```

i tried using VALUES as well:

```
 sql="""UPDATE table SET (value1,value2,value3) VALUES (%s) WHERE id=%s"""
```

This one gave me mostly syntax errors for VALUES

i'm keep getting : **"the query contains more than one '%s' placeholder"
or "not all values formatted during string formatting"**  ," Syntax error in ___"

How should i write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

execute_values only supplies one "item", so only takes one %s.  But that item is a double composite (a list of tuples).  This syntax is natural for INSERT, but is a bit odd for UPDATE.  So you need to write the statement a bit oddly.

```
sql = """UPDATE tableb SET value1 = v1, value2 = v2, value3 = v3 
         from (values %s) f(id, v1, v2, v3)
         WHERE tableb.id = f.id"""
for feat in features:
    parameters = [
                feat.id,
                feat.value1,
                feat.value2,
                feat.value3,
                 ]
    all_parameters.append(parameters)
execute_values(cur,sql,all_parameters)
```

Note how you need to assign aliases for the "table" and "columns" of the values construct right after the `(values %s)`, and then reference them by those aliases elsewhere.

Comment: Can I use a similar method for insert. My sql query includes two subqueries. #insert_query  = "INSERT INTO value (grid_id, attribute_id, date, value) VALUES ((select grid_id from grid where ST_Contains(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(%s %s)', 4326))), 
(SELECT attribute_id FROM attributes WHERE name=%s), %s, %s);". The query works via execute_batch. Can I use execute_values with minor changes?

Answer (score 2):

Your statement is fine, but you should be using cursor `execute()` here:

```py
sql = """UPDATE table
         SET value1 = %s, value2 = %s, value3 = %s, value4 = %s,
             value5 = %s, value6 = %s, value7 = %s, value8 = %s, value9 = %s
         WHERE id = %s"""

parameters = (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, id,)
        
cur.execute(sql, parameters)
```

`execute_values()` is intended to be used for inserts with a `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Hi, i know but i'm trying making it to work faster. And thought psycopg2 execute_values is the way

Comment: You are only updating a single row so `execute_values` or `execute_batch` are not going to really help. Reconfigure as @TimBiegeleisen has shown.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver updated as you didn't understand my question. How should i write it for updating multiple rows?

Comment: I understood the question as originally asked, you just did not ask the correct question. See [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) `execute_batch`.